# IR Jump Bag - What kind of bag/container to use?

Tags: tools, incident-response

I am working on putting together an Incident Response Jump Bag (detailed [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/935/what-should-be-included-in-a-jump-bag-and-how-often-should-it-be-reviewed)).

Any suggestions on what type of container/bag to use for this?  It seems like a lot of little items that could be packaged together, and some big items.

I have a messenger bag and backpack, but they don't really seem to cut it.

Anything else that I should take into consideration? (chain of custody issues, etc?)

Comment: This is really borderline security question...

Comment: I have to agree with AviD, the fact that the things in the bag are for ITSec purposes is secondary and only slightly relevant to the actual question, which is about packing.  Perhaps you could propose Packing.SE on Area51.

Comment: I have edited the question to better reflect what I am looking for.

Comment: I think this is a borderline question, but I think I'm fairly happy to have it here even if all it does is prompt people to think about things like chain of custody, which they might not otherwise...

Comment: Ah, I think the chain of custody is a very good *on* topic issue. Maybe turn some more focus to that, and other possible IR-specific issues, instead of asking your mom to pack your schoolbag :)

Comment: @Avid lol, well, I guess you can tell alot about a person by the questions they pose.  I never was good at packing my lunchbag...  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the amount of kit you require in your jump bag, you may want a wheeled trolley case or a rucksack, to avoid injury (speaking from experience, I once had to implement a wireless honeypot as part of incident response and the kit included 5 laptops (running simulations, logging etc) and my back ached for weeks)

In any case the only real restriction I would advise is **keeping it below airline maximum size and weight** considerations - putting forensic kit in hold luggage on the return effectively breaks the chain of custody, and if you do have to fly, leave your screwdrivers/multitool at home in case you aren't allowed to fly with it.